# How can I disable tap to click on Asus A55VD?

Tags: touchpad, asus

I need help to get Ubuntu 15.10 to detect the touchpad of my laptop (Asus A55VD). I really want to disable touchpad option "tap to click". I have tried some tutorials but I haven't achieved it.

Comment: So is the touchpad detected? Why don't you disable the tap in System Settings -> Mouse?

Comment: And 15.10 has not been released yet and it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following lines at the end of your `.bashrc`:

```
#Disable touchpad tap
synclient TapButton1=0
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
```

with `nano ~/.bashrc` or `gedit ~/.bashrc` from terminal.

Also you can create a simple script *disableTap.sh* anywhere as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient TapButton1=0
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
```

add executing permission from right click menu and add it to startup from settings (or type *startup* on unity dash).

Alternatively you can create an *init script* or *systemd unit* associated to that script.

Check all synclient's available options at  http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I've typed changes but i still founding problems with the driver. Terminal shows this message: "Couldn0t find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"